# Create a wordpress activation menu

Tags: php, wordpress

Can I create a installation menu for a wordpress plugin?
When I click on the activate button, a menu needs to appear to enter the default settings.
Is there any hooks or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook to redirect to the settings page upon activation.

If you really need a 'wizard' and redirecting to the settings page is not good enough. Then on the 'init' hook you could check whether a setting 'my_plugin_wizard_complete' exists and if it doesn't then register your wizard as a wordpress admin page and redirect there instead. You would need to set the setting when the wizard is completed.